# How to stop WPF Grid from automatically inserting margins on child elements

Tags: wpf, grid, visual-studio-2012, margin

I have the most annoying problem with Visual Studio 2012 and WPF I was hoping to get some help with. I have a simple Grid with child elements, say, TextBlocks, with the grid's cells. The TextBlocks are setup to be positioned RELATIVELY within the cell (using HorizontalAlignment of Left, for example). Everything is fine until I dare to resize its column or row of the Grid. Visual Studio then inserts Margin and Width/Height attributes in keeping with the resulting positions of parent/child elemnts. This all happens silently and I don't notice it until later if I decide to reduce the size of the column further, all of the sudden the TextBlock gets clipped, due to its Margin attributes that were inserted. I have to go through every child element and remove these extra attributes manually. I have had to do this close to 100 times on my current project, and I cannot find anything on the web to figure out how to tell Visual Studio to BACK OFF and stop taking these liberties that steal the nice formatting I'm trying to achieve. 
Here's a code snippet for reference. But this has happened on many different instances of Grids in my project.

```
<Grid  Canvas.Left="435" Canvas.Top="138" Height="61" Width="192">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="11*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Subtotal:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
</Grid>
```

... and after the resizing of column 0:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Subtotal:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="0,7" Width="47"  />
```

Surely there are others out there who have experienced this issue. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much you can do about the odd automatic behaviors in the XAML designer. As a general word to the wise, you are often better of using XAML text editor instead of the designer to edit your xaml.

Fortunately in your special case there is a solution. The behavior depends on where you acutally grab the column with the mouse:

If you grab it at the top it will set new margins.
[image: grab at the top]

if you grab it below (at the line) it will not set/change margins.
[image: grab at the bottom]

**Update: This feature does not exist in VS 2012 anymore.**

You can now change the behavior of a column resize with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and/or the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. But none of the behaviors yield the result that you're after.

In case all your items within the grid do not have a `Width` and a `Margin` set, your best bet is to resize the columns without any modifier key (in VS2012 it should not destroy the layout visually, it should just add the unecessary `Margin`, `Height` and `Width` properties) and then in the *Document Outline* window multiselect all the elements and in the *Properties* view Klick the *Set To Auto* button. This will delete the unnecessary properties.

[image: Set To Auto]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've accepted it because I remember seeing those little mouse cursor symbols (look like antennas) show up in VS 2010, but now when i tried it in VS 2012, they do not appear and likewise I cannot do any dragging of columns (except at the very top). Any ideas? Otherwise, via XAML I'm forced to calculate the column ratios taht would result from click-and-drag in the designer.

Comment: I'm surprised by the lack of enthusiasm for this question/answer. Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is just not to use the design surface for anything except a visual reference.

I use the text editor as otherwise you have virtually no control over your XAML - I find it highly annoying that drag/dropping a control on the design surface automatically sets the margins and alignment etc

The way I see it - everything in XAML should auto scale - the only time you should need to set an absolute value on something is when you absolutely need it to be that size ... and even then it's probably better to do it via a style (e.g. a standard button need not scale to the width of the entire application - so an explicit size is ok...), margins should always be used to set **margins** on items, not used for layout (which is what the designer seems to think is OK)

I use the design surface as a reference - you can also click on an element and the XAML code will sync to the item you clicked on (most of the time) - but for the love of god, don't drag anything or you will be in for a world of hurt!

Comment: You can doubleclick on the toolboxbutton of the control you want to add instead of dragging and dropping it. That way the control will be added without any margins to the currently selected/active element. There are a lot of tricks like that, they are just not easy to discover. Once you know them all, the designer is actually pretty usable. I still tend to prefer the XAML texteditor too though.

Comment: Good tip - I didn't know this, I like using the designer to add controls because the 3rd party stuff usually needs a load of xmlns declarations and otherwise it's manual entry time! Doubt I'll ever use the editor over the XAML text editor though!

Comment: ReSharper can help you with a lot of XAML stuff very nicely too, e.g. when adding a custom/3rd party control without the designer it will automatically add the namesapce decalration.

Comment: I don't have the horsepower for ReSharper and everything else I'm running, I've got the silverlight SDK bug too (which keeps coming back again and again) where it takes about 2/3 minutes to load the toolbox! Would be nice for the company to splash out on the devs instead of just the consultants for a change!

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips; as a newby to the world of WPF (and working alone) I'll take whatever experience-won knowledge I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I set margins on all elements on all sides and if they get reset, I set them again. Without settings margins, the XAML designer inserts both margins and spans as well which breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is very old. But I found a simple solution for any version of Visual Studio. I think this might be very useful to others who face the same problem.

First drag from the top as shown in below figure:

[image]

Leave  your mouse and note down the column width of each column.

Press Ctrl+Z for undo.

Then change the column width from XAML.

Now you will get your column appropriately sized and there will not be any extra margins or height or width added to any of your components inside grid.